# How do I extract the root domain from a domain using the URI class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Say I have a URL like this: `http://www.rubinassociatespa.com/AccountantBocaRaton.html`

I want to just extract the base domain - `http://www.rubinassociatespa.com`

I can't figure out how to do it using the ruby URI class though without doing string manipulation.

```
[36] pry(#<YPCrawler::PageParser>)> @url
=> "http://www.rubinassociatespa.com/AccountantBocaRaton.html"
[37] pry(#<YPCrawler::PageParser>)> URI(@url).scheme
=> "http"
[38] pry(#<YPCrawler::PageParser>)> URI(@url).host
=> "www.rubinassociatespa.com"
```

To do it using string manipulation, I would have to do something like:

```
URI(@url).scheme + "://" + URI(@url).host
```

But that seems hacky.

Is there a more 'native' way to do this? Some cool method or something within the `URI` class that can elegantly handle this?

Comment: there are not out-of-box methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use:

```
▶ uri.to_s[/\A.*(?=#{uri.path}\z)/]
#⇒ "http://www.rubinassociatespa.com"
```

This is safe, since it’s exactly what the base domain is: the whole URI without the path.

Please note, that there won’t be any unified method due to URI class [extensibility](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#module-URI-label-Adding+custom+URIs) and the flexibility of the RFC itself.

Comment: It breaks if uri has query. Then maybe it's better to use OP's solution.